# Write markdown documents with R code that doesn't work, on purpose

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

I'm experimenting with using Markdown to write homework problems for a course that involves some R coding. Because these are homework sets, I intentionally write code that throws errors;. Is it possible to use Markdown to display R code in the code style without evaluating it (or to trap the errors somehow)?

Comment: Would it be easier to execute the code in R console, then copypaste the console as an input to Markdown?

Comment: But then can I get Markdown to format the code as code, rather than as text?

Comment: I haven't used markdown, so can't say for sure, but this bit from the help pages suggests you might have to do some minor pre-editing: "R code blocks enclosed by “‘r ... \n“‘ will automatically be syntax highlighted."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using R markdown, putting `eval=FALSE` in the chunk options should work.  Or use `try()`.  Or, if you're using `knitr` as well, I believe that the default chunk option `error=FALSE` doesn't actually stop the compilation when it encounters an error, but just proceeds to the next chunk (which sometimes drives me crazy).

Comment: From knitr news: - inline R code also respects the option opts_knti$get('stop_on_error')`  now, e.g. if we set this option to `2L`, R will completely stop when errors occurs in inline R code

Comment: thanks, I think I might have known that but haven't gotten around to implementing it as a habitual thing ...